# Do math to one specific element/value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Here is my array: `[2017, 04, 31]`

as you can see, that is todays date. but its not really todays date because we have to subtract -1 to the month. so i need the final result to be: `[2017, 03, 31]`.

I tried with `.map()` but that is elements/values in the array. here is the example:

```
var array = [2017, 04, 31];

var new_array = array.map( function(value) { 
    return value - 1;
} );
```

how can i do this and -1 from the month (04) so it will be `[2017, 03, 31]`?

Comment: `array[1] -= 1`

Comment: *"that is todays date"* - No it's not. Also, you can't have `04` as a number, it would have to be a string `"04"` if you want to keep the leading zero.

Comment: 04 is an octal number, which in this case is identical to 4 - you might want to switch to decimal notation by removing the leading zero.

Comment: what month are we talking about? Is this the 31st of March or April? Do you need to decrement the month for passing it to `new Date()`? Then how about `new Date(array[0], array[1]-1, array[2])`

Answer (score 0):

To get and set valid date, you can use `Date` constructor in form `year`, `month` which is 0-based, `date`, `.toJSON()`, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\d+)/g, "'$1'"` to surround each set of digits with quotation marks; `.slice()` with parameters `0` and `10` to get `YYYY-MM-DD` portion of date, `.split()` with parameter `"-"` to get array of strings representing valid date.

It is not possible to get `[2017, 04, 31]` or `["2017", "04", "31"]` as a valid date. April has a maximum of 30 dates.

To get last date in April and the last date in March using an array as values to set as parameters to `new Date()` call

```js
var arr = [2017, 4, 30];

function dateAsArrayYYYYMMDD(array) {
  return new Date(array.toString().replace(/(\d+)/g, "'$1'"))
         .toJSON().slice(0, 10).split("-");
}

// get last date in April as array of string values
var date = dateAsArrayYYYYMMDD(arr);

console.log(date);
 
// set date reflecting last date in March,
// assign to `date` variable identifier

arr[1] -= 1;
arr[2] += 1;

date = dateAsArrayYYYYMMDD(arr);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: `04` is a valid way to write a `Number` value but I would still avoid it due to being interpreted as octal in non-strict mode.

Comment: @le_m Not sure what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: why would year and day end up as strings if the "input" is `var array = [2017, 04, 31];`

Comment: @JaromandaX Updating Answer presently to use `Date`, `String()`, `Array` methods. Not sure how input can be `04` as a number other than what is pointed out by @le_m

Comment: "hard coded" input could be 0x04, or 0000004, or 4.0 - result is all the same - I just don't understand your "quotes" in the comments

Comment: @JaromandaX Which quotes at which comments? Depends on context. Just re-read Question and noticed 2017-04-31 is not a valid date. April has 30 days, not 31. Not sure how `var array = [2017, 04, 31]` was derived in reference to a date. The max for April would be `[2017, 04, 30]`, whether represented as `Number` or `String`

Comment: which quotes? erm `// ["2017", 3, "31"]` the ones around year and day .... and yes, I do know that 2017-04-31 is not a valid date ... in JS you could `new Date(2017,3,31)` (3 because that's april) and get no error ... you end up with 1 may 2017 ... you can even `new Date(2017,-46,-77)` if you want with no error

Comment: @JaromandaX  The quotes demonstrate that the expected format and increment or decrement procedures could return unexpected result if not taking into consideration conversion from `Number` to `String` or `String` to `Number`.  Would suggest to OP to use string values, `Date` and `Date` methods with `Array` methods to adjust valid date, if decide to continue updating Answer. At some point OP would be welcome to chime in as to how `[2017, 04, 31]` was derived, or correct erroneous initial code at Question

Comment: sorry, I thought what you put after `//` was the *expected content* of the array - I misunderstood your obscure reason for putting quotes around arbitrary items in the array

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array  = [2017,04,22];
array[1] = 03;
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Then array[1]=-1

Comment: the original array is hard coded, so why not just hard code 3 instead of 4 :p

Comment: @MohitBajoria, I think you confused `array[1] = -1` with `array[1] -= 1` in your comment. It's a tiny but substantial difference.